# Jquery changing different backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following Jquery code...on button click it changes background color with some interval...what i want when button is clicked second time (3rd & so on) it start showing next bunch of colors when reached last it should stop on last color for each set...sorry for asking much detailed help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function() {
    var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'],
        colorIndex = 0,
        $body = $('body');

    setInterval(function(){ $body.css('background', colors[colorIndex++ % colors.length])}, 500);
});
});
```

here is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/nHKFK/

thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want the button not to change the colour after the last colour is reached?

Comment: @Aamir could you be more clear? just check LightStyle's answer then respond

Comment: it should pause on the last each set of when clicked second time it should show next and so on...when reached to the end can be start again if user want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me, but if I have understood your question this should do the trick([here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHKFK/2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colorSets = [],
        body = $(document.body),
        colorSetsIndex = 0, //goes from 0 to the max length of colorSets
        colorIndex = 0, //goes from 0 to the max length of the current colorSet
        started = false,
        intervalId;
    //add all the sets you want
    colorSets.push(["blue", "green", "yellow"]);
    colorSets.push(["grey", "red", "purple"]);
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        if (started) return;
        started = true;
        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            var currentSet = colorSets[colorSetsIndex];
            body.css('background', currentSet[colorIndex]);
            colorIndex += 1;
            if (colorIndex === currentSet.length) {
                colorSetsIndex++;
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
            if (colorSetsIndex === colorSets.length) {
                var restart = confirm('Restart?');
                if (!restart) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    $("button").off('click');
                    return;
                }
                colorSetsIndex = 0;
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: was writing the similar solution - will definitely upvote you as your fiddle works correctlty but does the OP wants to `unbind` click event on button as well after clearing the timeInterval ?

Comment: "It's not totally clear to me", unfortunately. If the OP will give me a more detailed explanation I'll edit the script, but this is what I understood from the question :)

Comment: yeah same doubt. Have questioned OP hope he replies back with more clarity

Comment: thanks for the answer dear. its fulfilling 50% of functionality...i want to add more sets of colors as well if button is clicked second time it should show up next bunch of colors... for e.g. when button is clicked first it should show 'blue,green,yellow' when clicked second time clicked it should show 'grey,red,white' and so on...please let me know if you are still not clear...thanks again...

Comment: Do you want the background change to be stopped when it reaches the last element of the list, before the new click of the button? And what happens if the user arrives at the last set of colors?

Comment: when it reaches last set he should be prompted if he want wants to start it again or not...

Comment: +1 but just a simple note : `unbind` is deprecated so better to use `off` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/